# $T_c = \{U\subset X | X-U \mbox{ is countable or $X$}\}$ is a topology

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

I need to prove that the set:

$$T_c = \{U\subset X | X-U \mbox{ is countable or $X$}\}$$ is a topology.

First of all, $\emptyset\in T_c$ because $X-\emptyset = X$ which is by definition a member of the set. Also, $X\in T_c$ because $X-X = \emptyset$ which is countable.

I now need to pick $U_i$, which are members of $T_c$ and show that $\cup U_i$ is in $T_c$. In order for the union to be in $T_c$ we must have $X-\cup U_i$ being countable or $X$, so:

$$X-\cup U_i = \cap(X-U_i)$$

Now, if all $X-U_i$ are countable, then the intersection is countable. If one of the $X-U_i$ is $X$, then the other $X-U_k$'s must be countable, and so the intersection must be countable.

Is this part right?

Now, for the finite intersection, we must have that $X-\cap U_i$ is countable, but
$$X-\cap U_i = \cup (X-U_i)$$

if all $X-U_i$ are countable, then the union is countable. If one of $X-U_i$ is $X$, then the union is $X$, so this is in $T_c$

Is my proof ok?

Comment: Looks fine and complete to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is correct, but you can shorten it: you can remove "If one of the $X−U_i$ is $X$, then the other $X−U_k$'s must be countable, and so the intersection must be countable." and remember that "countable union of countable sets is countable" for the last part.

Comment: what is a countable union? also, why I must take off the first phrase?

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs is a union $\bigcup_{i\in I}U_i$ where $I$ is countable.

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs about the first phrase, because the previous case also serves for this.